# Does the entropy of a ChatGPT sentence match that of the output?

Tags: information-theory

In [this tweet](https://twitter.com/nntaleb/status/1700210057663885394), Nassim Taleb states the following:

> If a chatbot writes a complete essay from a short prompt, the entropy of the essay must be exactly that of the initial prompt, no matter the length of the final product.

He then continues:

> If the entropy of the output > prompt, you have no control over your essay.
> In the Shannon sense, with a temperature of 0, you send the prompt and the reveivers will recreate the exact same message.
> In a broader sense, with all BS being the same ornament, receivers get the same message in different but equivalent wrapping.

I have some intuitive feeling of understanding this. It reminds me of this joke about ChatGPT I found somewhere on Twitter, which was dubbed "The ChatGPT future of job applications":

[image]

If used in a specific way, ChatGPT can be viewed as a translator between different forms of the same message. It can translate not only between languages, but also between different styles of writing. Thus, the information content (and thus information entropy) stays the same.

However, I have trouble to really understand Taleb's statement. If I ask ChatGPT "Who is the current President of the United States?", it will answer "The current President of the United States is Joseph Biden." - in this case it should be absolutely clear that the output has more information in it. Maybe Taleb's statement is meant from the point of view of a world in which everone has access to an encyclopedia - in that case, the output has the same entropy, because everyone can just look up who the current POTUS is.

[This answer tweet](https://twitter.com/sean_a_mcclure/status/1700232196244832573) argues that each ChatGPT answer must have **lower** entropy than the prompt, since

> Any expanding done on the part of the LLM is merely resolving the uncertainty by providing specific instances of that which is stated generally by the prompt.

> These specific instances, by definition, have lower entropy by virtue of their specificity. Thus it would take all possible essays that could be written to match the entropy of the original prompt.

> This makes the prompt the entity with the highest possible information content.

Again, this somehow makes sense, but only if you assume some kind of all-knowing, because if the "receiver" does not have access to an encyclopedia, the ChatGPT output surely has more information in it than just the prompt.

So, I'm looking for an answer that explains the relationship between the entropy of a ChatGPT prompt and that of its output. Under what exact conditions is the entropy of the prompt higher/equal/lower than/to that of the output?

Comment: How is the entropy of a ChatGPT prompt/ the output defined?

Comment: @jd27 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)

Comment: This all sounds very vague and informal.  If these things can be sensibly quantified, then it should be possible to simply check a lot of cases.  If not, then I'm not sure what, if anything, can be said.

Comment: @lulu agree. But as pointed out in my question, there must be some assumptions under which it becomes formal.

Comment: @JonasSourlier i am aware of the definition of entropy. But what is the exact probability space setup to discuss the entropy of ChatGPT output/input? What i am asking you is to translate the vague question into a precise mathematical question that can be precisely answered.

Comment: Entropy is a property of a probability distribution; a fixed string doesn't have entropy.

Comment: Why must there?  I think the comment was intended in a vague and informal way.

Comment: @jd27 I'm not sure if I can do that. But I suppose it makes sense that Taleb's tweet assumes as probability space some kind of English language word frequencies. The word "the" carries much less entropy/information than the words "President" or "Biden", because it is much more frequent than the latters. AFAIK that's how you normally treat entropy and information of text. But again, Information Theory is not something I'm trained in, that's why I'm asking here.

Comment: Could this problem not be stated without mentioning the annoying ChatGPT-bot ? This is promotion ChatGPT has not deserved.

Comment: @Peter it could, but since I do not know how to phrase this into a mathematical rigorous question, I needed to link to Taleb's tweet, which mentions the bot.

Comment: @Karl agree, but the entropy of a probability distribution like the English language is a sum. It is the "average amount of surprise, i.e. real information". Now if you pick one event, i.e. one specific string, you can talk about its information content by summing over the "surprise" of its parts, i.e. its words. "The house is big" has certainly less entropy than "Nauseant biblioclepts abjure serendipity."

Comment: To be clear:  unless I am misreading, the tweet is aspirational, not factual.  That is, there is no claim that, logically, the entropies are required to match.  Rather, there's an informal notion that it would be "better" if the machine neither added nor subtracted information and just provided an information-free wrapper for whatever was in the prompt.  Or is this not what was intended?

Comment: @lulu thanks, that makes it much clearer. But I still wonder: how can the question "Who's president?" and the answer "Biden." be considered to contain the same amount of information?

Comment: I would say that it clearly contained *more* information, which would be counter the spirit of the comment.  That is, the system is meant (in some sense) merely to embroider, not to compose the message.

Comment: IMO this is simplistic, as such "gotchas" nearly always are. If the essay reader/evaluator knew every possible essay, then yes, the entropy being added is simply the entropy of the prompt. But the evaluator presumably does not know every essay (given that they're, well, human), so from this perspective some information is indeed being added. Taleb's statement in a sense is equivalent to saying that because the text of wikipedia is fixed, you'd learn nothing about information theory from reading its wiki page

Comment: (contd.) that you wouldn't learn already from the statement "you can learn about information theory from reading its wiki page," which is kind of absurd. You can formalise things more (e.g., given the probabilistic criticism, you can study Kolmogorov complexity of certain strings given only the prompt and given the prompt and the generation, et c.), but I doubt this is a very useful exercise.